# Inequality for a harmonic function with gradient bounded from below

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Consider $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ a compact set . Let $R > 0 $ such that $B(0,R) \supset K$ and $\partial B(0,R) \cap \partial K = \emptyset .$

Let $u : \overline{B(0,R)} \rightarrow \mathbb  R$ a  function satifying

1. $u$ is harmonic in $B(0,R) \setminus K$
2. $u = 1 $ in $K$
3. $u = 0$ in $\partial B(0,R)$
4. Exists a neighbourhood $V$ of $K$  and a constant $\alpha >0$  ($\alpha$ depends only of $u$) such that $|\nabla u(x)| \geq \alpha$ for all $x \in V \setminus K.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ small such that $\{ u > 1- \epsilon \} \subset V$ (I know this epsilon exists)

Define $u_{\epsilon} (z) = \displaystyle\frac{u(z) - (1- \epsilon)}{\epsilon} , z \in \{ u > 1 - \epsilon\}$.

I am studying an article, and appears that the author is using  this

$$ |u_{\epsilon} (x) - u_{\epsilon} (y)| \geq \displaystyle\frac{\alpha}{\epsilon} |x - y|  $$

for $x \in \partial \{  u > 1 - \epsilon \}$ and $y  \in \{u > 1 - \epsilon \}$.

I am trying to show this for days, but I am not seeing how ... If I understand then I understand Lemma 3.2 of [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.6578).

Someone can give me a help to prove or disprove the inequality ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the claimed inequality is not that strong. It says that for each $x$ with $u_\epsilon(x)=0$ there exists $y$ with $u_\epsilon(y)=l$ such that $|x-y|\le cl$. Here I write $c=\frac{\epsilon }{\alpha}$ for brevity.

To see why, note that $|\nabla u_\epsilon|\ge c^{-1}$ in the relevant region. Starting from $x$, follow the curve of steepest ascent, i.e., the direction of $\nabla u_\epsilon$. Traveling along this curve with unit speed, we see the values of $u_\epsilon$ increasing at the rate of at least $c^{-1}$. Therefore, we will reach the level $l$ by traveling no further than $cl$.

---

*More details*: The curve of steepest ascent is  the solution of the ODE $$x'(t) = \frac{\nabla u_\epsilon(x(t))}{ |\nabla u_\epsilon(x(t))|}$$ starting at a point $x$ with $u_\epsilon(x)=0$. By the chain rule,  $$ \frac{d}{dt}  u_\epsilon(x(t)) = |\nabla u_\epsilon(x(t)|  \ge c^{-1}$$ Therefore, $u(x(t))$ will reach $l$ on the interval $ 0\le t\le cl $.

Comment: can you explain more the part :  "Therefore, we will reach the level l by traveling no further than cl"  please?

Comment: @mathstudent Added

Comment: Hi Norman. do you know a reference with a proof of the existence of the curve in this context?